# How to change Div class based on number range

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF and dont know how to manage to replace div class name if the custom_field number is

```
equal and less then 30 class="color1"
equal and less then 50 class="color2"
equal and less then 90 class="color3"

Can you please tell me how to do that?


if( $post_objects ):
foreach( $post_objects as $post_object):
echo the_field("casino_rating", $post_object->ID);
endforeach; endif;
```

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the casino rating and display a different class depending on what appears?

In this case you could use this code:

```
if( $post_objects ):

    foreach( $post_objects as $post_object ):

        $casino_rating = get_field("casino_rating", $post_object->ID);

        // This part here will decide what class to get
        if( $casino_rating < 30 ){

            echo 'class="color1"';

        } elseif( $casino_rating < 50 ){

            echo 'class="color2"';

        } elseif( $casino_rating < 90 ){

            echo 'class="color3"';

        }


    endforeach;


endif;
```

You might want to be careful though and make sure this is only outputting `class=` if there's no other class attached to the element, otherwise there'll be HTML errors.

Comment: Thanks alot mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more compact version that should achieve the same thing

```
if( $post_objects ):
    foreach( $post_objects as $post_object ):
        $rating = get_field("casino_rating", $post_object->ID);

        $color = ($rating >= 31) ? "color2" : "color1";
        $color = ($rating >= 51 ) ? "color3" : $color;
        echo 'class="'.$color.'"';

    endforeach;
endif;
```

or if you are going to use this a lot make a function for it At the bottom of your page

```
 function color($rating) {
        $color = ($rating >= 31) ? "color2" : "color1";
        $color = ($rating >= 51 ) ? "color3" : $color;
        return $color;
    }
```

Then you can do

```
 if( $post_objects ):
        foreach( $post_objects as $post_object ):
            $rating = get_field("casino_rating", $post_object->ID);
            echo 'class="'.color($rating).'"';
        endforeach;
    endif;
```